# algorithm for tree encode and representation

Tags: algorithm, tree

My objective is about generate a expression `tree` on local machine, and transmit the `tree` to remote host via network. Then the remote host can `eval` according the expression tree. I have thought a way that encode the tree into two strings, which represent its preorder and midorder traversal sequence. Is there any other good way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you think of using XML? It seems it is designed to encode such a structure

Comment: XML is actually a good way I have not thought of before.  But the remote machine may be an embedded system with no OS running. I have to port light XML parser for it. I will keep it in mind. Thx :-)

Comment: In case of embedding system, i guess you have to write a parser (in C eventually) and have it fast and small. In this case maybe there is something lighter than an XML parser. A possibility is using a parenthesized representation, something like (a(b(d, e, f), c(g(h, i), k))). This representation is usually easiest to parse, either directly in C or generated by a tool such as yacc.

Answer (score 0):

Huffman encoding perhaps? Maybe?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: Nope. What I want is encode the tree. Huffman encoding is about encoding something according a specific tree.